# How to resize container slick carousel to 100% of parent?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I use library [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).
There is the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="item" title=""></div>
        <div class="item" title=""></div>
        <div class="item" title=""></div>
        <div class="item" title=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And styles:

```
.parent {
   height:100%; // 100% of page
}

.item {
 height:100%; // Element in slide
}
```

How to resize content inside `.slider` that if will be 100% of parent container?

Answer (score 1):

Give `.slider` and `.item` heights of `100%` and they should adhere to the height of `.parent`.

http://codepen.io/johnniebenson/pen/mPNJqw

```
.slider {
    height: 100%;
}

.slider .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```